# node-RED json object - how to extract a value example code

Tags: json, node-red

I am trying to extract values from a json file.  I can do this with function node when it is posted from a webhook on my github page.  But from another site I cant seem to get this working. This is what I use to get the value on github to test.

```
var msg2 = {payload: msg.payload.comment.user.login };

return msg2;
```

This is the code I get from the other server.  I just want two value from this below.  When I save the incomming message directly with a save node this is whats in the json file.

```
{"payload":"{\"id\":33,\"status\":\"completed\",\"totalAmount\":103,\"tipAmount\":0,\"feeAmount\":4,\"settleAmount\":99,\"requiredAmount\":null,\"date\":\"2017-09-22T06:51:33Z\",\"snapCode\":\"To9tQhiV\",\"snapCodeReference\":\"06ce2405-1688-4cb7-aa26-6df25c053f8c\",\"userReference\":\"\",\"merchantReference\":null,\"statementReference\":null,\"authCode\":null,\"deliveryAddress\":null,\"extra\":{\"merchantReference\":\"AB11FFBC56\"}}"}
```

I just need totalAmount and merchantReference in the extra field.

Please assist and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `payload` is a JSON String. To access its contents you must first parse it to a JavaScript Object.

Add a `JSON` node in front of your `Function` node - that will convert `msg.payload` for you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply I have just tried this.  See screenshot.  This is the code I use in the function.  Should I tick the box FORMAT JSON STRING? inline `var msg2 = {payload: msg.payload.snapcode};`

Comment: Sorry I see I cant add pictures in the comments but the flow is as follow: HTTP IN NODE(POST) - JSON - FUNCTION - DEBUG  It returns this after the JSON node: inline `{    "payload": "{\"id\":36,\"status\":\"completed\",\"totalAmount\":106,\"tipAmount\":0,\"feeAmount\":4,\"settleAmount\":102,\"requiredAmount\":null,\"date\":\"2017-09-.............\":\"06ce2405-1688-4cb7-aa26-6df25c053f8c\",\"userReference\":\"\",\"merchantReference\":null,\"statementReference\":null,\"authCode\":null,\"deliveryAddress\":null,\"extra\":{\"merchantReference\":\"AB11FFBC56\"}}"}'`

Comment: Edit the original question to add details